# Using Javascript RegExp object

Tags: javascript, regex

I must have a syntax error in my code but I can't see it. [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/waldermort/2Pbm3/)

```
var comma = ',，';
var stop = '.。';
var expression = '/[]+/';

expression = expression.substr(0,2) + comma + stop + expression.substr(2);
expression = new RegExp(expression,'g');

var res = "foo,吧。baz".split(expression);

for ( var n=0; n < res.length; n++ ) {
}
```

I'm expecting `res.length` to be 3 but it is always 1 and returns the full string. What am I missing?

Comment: The problem is that you don't need `/` if you use `RegExp` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var expression = '/[]+/';
```

Should be

```
var expression = '[]+';
```

Also, adjust the substring indices accordingly
http://jsfiddle.net/2Pbm3/4/

Answer (score 2):

`/` is used as delimiter for `RegExp` literal. e.g. `/[a-zA-Z]/g`

`/` is not needed when you pass a pattern to the `RegExp` constructor. e.g. `new RegExp('[a-zA-Z]', 'g')`

To resolve the problem, remove the `/` (and modify the rest of your code):

```
var expression = '[]+';
```

Or you can just pass a RegExp literal directly:

```
var res = "foo,吧。baz".split(/[,，.。]+/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you creat your Regex you're using this: `var expression = '/[]+/';`. The `/` delimiters are for use when you're delaring a regex like this:

```
var expression = /[]+/;   // note: no quotes.
```

You're using `new Regexp()`, so they're not required in your string. Removing them gives this:

```
var comma = ',，';
var stop = '.。';
var expression = '[]+';

expression = expression.substr(0,1) + comma + stop + expression.substr(1);
expression = new RegExp(expression,'g');

var res = "foo,吧。baz".split(expression);

for ( var n=0; n < res.length; n++ ) {
  var item = document.createElement('li');
  item.innerHTML = res[n];
  document.getElementById('list').appendChild( item );
}
```

Which does what you expect. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Pbm3/2/). I've adjusted the string indices and the loop index so that things work...

Answer (score 0):

Working like this :

```
var comma = ',，';
var stop = '.。';
var expression = '[]+';

expression = expression.substr(0,1) + comma + stop + expression.substr(1);
expression = new RegExp(expression,'g');

var res = "foo,吧。baz".split(expression);

for ( var n=0; n < res.length; n++ ) {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerHTML = res[n];
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild( item );
}
```